# how can i calculate the difference between two dates from the user input?

Tags: date, python-3.x

This is my code so far:

```
       import datetime
from time import strptime
leapyear = 0

isValid = False
while not isValid:
    in_date = input(" Please in put a year in the format dd/mm/yyyy ")

    try:
        d = strptime(in_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        isValid=True
    except:
        print ("This is not in the right format")



date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/""%m/""%Y")

in_date = in_date.split('/')
date = date.split('/')

in_date = [int(i) for i in in_date]
date = [int(i) for i in date]

date_f = [str(i) for i in date]
date_f = '/'.join(date_f)

in_date_f = [str(i) for i in in_date]
in_date_f = '/'.join(in_date_f)

newdate = [] 
in_date[0], in_date[2] = in_date[2], in_date[0]
date[0], date[2] = date[2], date[0]
z = "/"
if in_date > date:
    newdate.insert((0),(in_date[2] % date[2]))
    newdate.insert((1),(in_date[1] % date[1]))
    newdate.insert((2),(in_date[0] % date[0]))

    print("Current Date:", date_f)
    print("you are:", newdate[2],"year(s)",newdate[1],"month(s) and",newdate[0],"days away          from:",in_date_f)

else:
    print("Please input a date thats higher than todays.")
```

At the moment i have taken today's date and then taken away that from the user input date which has to be higher than the current date. but this gives the wrong answer because it hasnt taken in the fact of the days in a month the and the months in a year.

how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

[`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html) objects are subtractable and comparable, so there is no problem in doing:

```
userDate = strptime(in_date, '%d/%m/%Y')

if userDate > datetime.datetime.today():
    # ...
```

or

```
if userDate.date() > datetime.datetime.today().date():
    # ....
```

or to calculate the difference:

```
diff = userDate - datetime.datetime.today()
```

Comment: with this method i get an exception useing the - to take way both the list and the datetime.

Comment: @user3077551 The point is, don't use a list - use `datetime` objects. Note I'm using `userDate` instead of your `in_date`.